# R: all row sums must be >0 in the community matrix: remove empty sites

Tags: r

I have searched for related topics as the one I'm asking about, but I was unable to find the solution to my problem.

All I am trying to do is read in my data to r for DCA. My code is below with error message:

```
> mydata <- read.table(file="file:///D:/Projects/Late Cretaceous/R Stuff/R Read In_Planktics.txt", header=TRUE,row.names=1, sep=",")
> mydata.ra <- decorana(mydata, ira=1)
Error in decorana(mydata, ira = 1) : 
  all row sums must be >0 in the community matrix: remove empty sites
```

I have used rowSums() and it shows that I have data in every row but they all =0 . I have double checked all my rows (and columns) and there is a value for all my data; everything sums >0. I have updated everything in r. Is there something wrong with the code, or do I need to modify anything? I am new at this so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please show at least the `str(x)` of your data. Could it be that the data is not numeric?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand that : > str(mydata)
'data.frame': 33 obs. of  0 variables

Comment: Please edit your original question. Comment section isn't suited for pasting a lot of code or data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found an answer here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-July/246090.html

I had included samples where I didn't observe any individuals so I had to remove those surveys to include only samples where at least one species had been observed